# Restrict calls to WCF service per minute, per method, per IP

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, configuration, throttling

I'd like to restrict the number of calls to a particular method on my WCF service, by any distinct IP, to **x** calls per timeframe **y**.

So for example, if IP `10.0.1.1` calls the method `register` more than 5 times in a particular minute (call it minute `x`), when it it tries to call that method a sixth time in that minute it is blocked until minute (`x + 1`).

This is because the only non-token authorized call on my system is the `register` call. I am worried that attempts to flood this method with calls will my server to struggle under load. There is quite a lot of processing behind this method, and it is designed to only be called occasionally.

I have looked into adding `ServiceThrottlingBehavior` to the config file, but this is global to the service, rather than local to a service method.

Is there a good / standardized way to do this, whether programatically or in a configuration file?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is by having a ServiceBehavior that adds an instance that implements [IInstanceContextInitializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/14/wcf-extensibility-initializers-instance-context-channel-call-context.aspx).

My implementation looks like this:

```
public class PerOperationThrottle: IInstanceContextInitializer
{
    static MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("foo", null);

    public void Initialize(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty  ep = message.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        // which action do we want to throttle
        if (message.Headers.Action.EndsWith("register") &&
            ep != null && 
            ep.Address != null)
        {
            // get the IP address 
            var item = cache[ep.Address];
            if (item == null)
            {
                // not found, so init
                cache.Add(
                    ep.Address,
                    new Counter { Count = 0 },
                    new CacheItemPolicy
                    {
                        SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) // 1 minute
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                // how many calls?
                var count = (Counter)item;
                if (count.Count > 5)
                {
                    instanceContext.Abort();
                    // not sure if this the best way to break
                    throw new Exception("throttle");
                }
                // add one call
                count.Count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use a somewhat naïve [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation that holds an instance per IP address of a my custom `Counter` class:

```
public class Counter
{
    public int Count;
}
```

To wire an instance of `PerOperationThrottle` to the service I have an helper class that combines the implementation for a [IServiceBehavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/22/wcf-extensibility-iservicebehavior.aspx) and [IEndpointBehavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/05/wcf-extensibility-iendpointbehavior.aspx):

```
public class PerOperationThrottleBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior,IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach(var ep in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
        {
            // add the EndpointBehavior
            ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(this);
        }      
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        // our PerOperationThrottle gets created and wired
        endpointDispatcher.
            DispatchRuntime.
            InstanceContextInitializers.
            Add(new PerOperationThrottle());
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {   
    }
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {   
    }
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    { 
    }
}
```

The empty methods belong to the interfaces but don't need any implementation. Make sure to remove the `throw new NotImplementedException();` though.

Finally we annotate the Service implementation class with our custom attribute `PerOperationThrottleBehavior`

```
[PerOperationThrottleBehavior]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string register(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

If the `register` operation gets called more than 5 times within a minute, the service throws an exception.

Comment: "ServiceEndpoint" does not contain EndpointBehaviors method. Do you know how to fix it? @rene

Comment: @ozkank are you on .Net 4.0? Upgrade if you are.

Comment: yes, It is running on .NET 4.0. I'll try it. And do you know any other way to this .Net 4.0? I think I have to fix this on this framework.:/