# How to use Throttling and Fault Contract in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-4

First of all sorry if it is repeated question any where.

Today I got some task saying that

> The throttling policy for SMS is 1000/min across all clients.

As well as another thing is : The SOAP fault returned when the throttling limit is breached is provided.

sendMessageFault is a class which contains

> Faultcode
>   Faultstring
>   Faultactor

Before coming to this forum I read some information in the Google for throttling and understanding is

```
<behavior name="serviceBehavior">

       <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16"

maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="10" />

     </behavior>
```

> Aappropriate settings for throttling behavior depend on a number of factors, including the instancing mode for the service, the number of services exposed by the application, and the desired outcome of throttling. In the next sections I'll discuss throttling in the context of these different factors.

Can anybody say for "The throttling policy for SMS is 1000/min across all clients" means and what configuration I have to set?

Can you show me some sample for fault contract?

Comment: I don't think you can do that type of throttling in the contract. For that you will probably have the application or custom service behaviour do custom throttling e.g. keep a count of number of messages in a minute and throw back an fault if the count is exceeded.

Comment: See this blog about throttling http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/concurrency-and-throttling-configurations-wcf-services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict calls to WCF service per minute, per method, per IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375303/restrict-calls-to-wcf-service-per-minute-per-method-per-ip)